# How can you call a function with a modifier in another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

How would you call a function with a modifier from another contract. Let the contracts be:

```
contract MyContract {
    address owner;
    modifier getModified (address owner) {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function func(address newOwnerAddress) getModified(owner) returns (address newOwner) {
        //....code....
    }
}

contract newContract {
    MyContract myContract = MyContract(0x08271...);

    function bid(uint amt, address _oldOwner, address _newOwner) returns(bool success) {
        if (amt > ...) {
            myContract.func(_newOwner,{getModified:_oldOwner})
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error `Error: Undeclared identifier: getModified` for `getModified` in [Remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/). I tried reading the docs but they also dont mention the funcition call with modifiers to other contracts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably intended to use `msg.sender` as `function func(address newOwnerAddress) getModified(msg.sender) ...`.  Then in `bid`, `myContract.func(_newOwner);` should work.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do and why you need a modifier to do it. The parameter `getModified(owner)` serves no purpose as it's always going to be the `owner` state variable which you already have in scope.  But now it's unclear whether your intent for `if (msg.sender != owner)` refers to the `owner` state variable or `owner` parameter.  Furthermore `if (msg.sender != owner)` will always be testing the calling contact against `owner` at it is the calling contract who is `msg.sender`.

Comment: Lastly, I've not seen `myContract.func(_newOwner,{getModified:_oldOwner})` as a valid calling convention.  `func` only takes one parameter.

Comment: `@o0ragman0o`, I have the test code here, the functions I am trying to interact is actually different. I have a function in some contract, and I want to call a specific function (which has a modifier), in that contract and answering your doubt,  in `if (msg.sender != owner)` refers to the `owner` parameter. But `@eth` shouldn't the modifier be mentioned while making a function call for `func`. So I think the question still stands: how do you call a function with a modifier from another contract?

Comment: You don't do anything different when calling a function with a modifier. There doesn't seem to be any reason for you to have a parameter to your modifier at all, but think about the modifier as  being a macro that gets called at compile-time. The `getModified(owner) ` modifier just substitutes the value of the global variable `owner` everwhere that the `getModified` definition uses the parameter `owner`

Comment: @TjadenHess it like I am working on a thing similar to a directory for a city or a company. There people will register through smart contracts, but they will be added to the directory only after voting by the respective caretakers. So here to make it for the "respective" caretakers, I wanted the voting function to have a modifier which takes their people's registration ID as input and if a validating person is eligible for that ID then he/she can vote. Hope you understood my problem. Because of this I needed the modifier to take input in form of `uint`. Alternate approach would also be helpful

Comment: You can't pass arguments into modifiers. Just put a check at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @TjadenHess something like the if statement inside the function and throw if condition not satisfied. 
`if (msg.sender != owner) {throw;}`
Sounds fair. Thank you so much `@TjadenHess`, never let down by the ethereum StackExchange community. 
cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @TjadenHess communicated in the comments and also from valuable inputs from others, this is the answer which can solve the problem. If you need to pass a value in the modifier to restrict the function from random calling then its better to put a check in the function rather than using a modifier.

```
contract MyContract{
    address owner = msg.sender;


function func(address newOwnerAddress) returns (address newOwner){
     if (msg.sender != owner) {throw;}
    //....Rest of the code remins same....
}

}

contract newContract{
    MyContract myContract = MyContract(0x08271...);

    function bid(uint amt, address _newOwner) returns(bool success){
        if (amt > ...){
        myContract.func(_newOwner)
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The calling contract does nothing abnormal and it needs no knowledge of the modifier. `modifier` is just a compiler sweetener that helps roll up repetitive code.

There are useful comments here about correctly designing your modifier to perform its intended function including passing arguments into the modifier. What it does and how it does it is an internal matter; of no concern to contracts that call it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked with solidity documents, and then mention that modifier adds a restrcition on the function call.
[Furthermore, you can restrict who can make modifications to your contract’s state or call your contract’s functions and this is what this page is about
The use of function modifiers makes these restrictions highly readable.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#restricting-access)

So if I have a contract which is takes a modifier input then, I think solidity should have something on that. I dont know the present scenario, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: The modifier can take an input, but the input is something visible inside the contract in that context. Modifier input can be a value passed into the function, but it doesn't modify the function interface. So you can function do(uint x) onlyModifier(x) ... and from outside contract.do(x);

Comment: okay! so it mean I cannot explicitly specify the value for the modifier for a function call. It should be declared in the contract itself.

I though we can use `myContract.func(_newOwner,{getModified:_oldOwner})` as a valid call. Thanks anyway `@rob`

Comment: Probably worth a vote or accept if it helped?